# How to use a template or partial inside a loop in a shortcode WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

To organize better my code, I would like to split some of my HTML in templates.
I have a loop inside a shortcode to get the posts:

```
function nh_shortcode_func($atts) {
    $posts = get_posts_by_category(.......);
    $html .= '';
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
       $post_id = $post->ID;
       $post_title = $post->post_title;
       $post_image = get_field('image', $post_id);

       $html .= **HERE THE CODE OF HTML WITH DIVS AND CLASSES**
    }
    return $html
}

add_shortcode('nh-content', 'nh_shortcode_func');
```

Instead, put my HTML code inside a variable, I would like to use another file with the HTML structure that I'm going to use to build the posts. Also, I would like to pass the dynamic data to it.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an include file and it will have access to the variables.  Something like:

```
function nh_shortcode_func($atts) {
    ob_start();
    include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/nh_shortcode.php';
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode('nh-content', 'nh_shortcode_func');
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks!
But how to include this in my foreach loop? I need to add the external HTML inside my $html variable to return inside the shortcode function.

Comment: I read more about the output buffer and It seems the best choice, Chris. Thanks!
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

Comment: Glad I could help! Yea, your foreach loop would just go inside the included file